# Use variable as name strings.xml

Tags: android, data-binding

I have some packages with a status.
in strings xml those status would be (translated to norwegian)

```
<string name="collectable">Kan hentes</string>
<string name="underway">Underveis</string>
<string name="transport_to_recipient">Leveres i dag</string>
<string name="returned">Sendt i retur</string>
<string name="archived">Utlevert</string>
<string name="sent">Sendt av deg</string>
<string name="unknown">Foreløpig ukjent</string>
```

so in my xml layout i want to do something like this:

```
android:text="@{`@strings/`+ parcelListItem.status.toString()}"
```

so the string names would match with the text. i am also using databinding for this to get parcelitem.status.

My problem is that it just prints out `"@strings/transport_to_receipient"`, not the actual translation. Is there a way to do this in a smart way, or should i just probably make a method on it?

Comment: Do you  have  dual language support in your app ? and which language is default  language  ?

Comment: Default language is english

Comment: this `strings`  belongs to `norwegian XML` ?

Comment: yes, it belongs to the norwegian xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the by using something like this:

```
public String getStringByString(String key) {
    String retString = key;
    int id = getResource().getIdentifier(key, "string", getPackageName());
    if (id != 0) {
        retString = getString(id);
    }

    return retString;
}
```

So basically this will try to get the resource name from you strings.xml file. If it fails will return the key.

Answer (score 0):

To access this string  `<string name="transport_to_recipient">Leveres i dag</string>` you need to update your resource configuration just LIKE THIS.

```
Resources resources= context.getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
DisplayMetrics metrics= resources.getDisplayMetrics();
configuration.setLocale(new Locale("nb")); //country code depend on your XML
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,metrics);
```

`nb` is country code might be in your case it will be different.
You will country code on the side of `string.xml` file in `Resource` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this method based on the answer above:

```
public static int getStringResourceIdByName(Context context, String stringId) {
    if (Utils.isNullOrBlank(stringId))
        stringId = ParcelListItem.Status.unknown.toString();
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "string", context.getPackageName());
}
```

and referred like this:

```
Utils.getStringResourceIdByName(context, parcelListItem.status.toString())
```